# Merging multiple QgsRasterLayer objects to create virtual raster (.vrt file) using gdal

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, gdalbuildvrt

I am creating multiple `QgsRasterLayer` objects in pyqgis and I need to merge them into a virtual raster .vrt file which will eventually be loaded as a layer in QGIS. 
The `QgsRasterLayer` objects are being created by passing imagery urls.

From what I could gather, I need to use `gdalbuildvrt` as mentioned at https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html but there the .vrt file is being created through list of .tif files.

I also checked the solution at [pyQGIS Merge raster layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260853/pyqgis-merge-raster-layers/260965) but there too they are loading the raster layers through .tif files.

Do I need to create .tif files from all the raster layer objects (as mentioned in [Exporting raster to rendered image using standalone script in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220225/exporting-raster-to-rendered-image-using-standalone-script-in-qgis)) and then use them to create .vrt or is there some other way to achieve this?